# Indexing Object using Enum

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have the following structure;

```
import data from "../data.min.json";

export enum TileType {
  tree = 'tree',
  rock = 'rock'
}

interface MapTile {
  walkable: boolean;
  positions: number[][];
}

export type MapTiles =  {
  [key in TileType]: MapTile
}

export interface Level1 {
  mapTiles: MapTiles;
}

export interface RootObject {
  level_1: Level1;
}

export default data as RootObject;
```

This works fine. However, when I try to use it like so;

```
const entries = Object.entries(data.level_1.mapTiles);
entries.forEach(([tileType, data]) => {
  
})
```

The value of tileType is a string, rather than an Enum. How can I get the enum value instead?

data structure:

```
{
  "level_1": {
    "mapTiles": {
      "tree": {
        "walkable": false,
        "positions": [
          [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 40 ], [ 0, 80 ]]
      },
      "rock": {
        "walkable": false,
        "positions": [
          [2, 4], [5, 7]
        ]
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the typings for `Object.entries` in `lib.esXXX.object.d.ts`. [In `lib.es2017.object.d.ts` for example](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts#L38), the typings look like this:

```js
entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
```

As you can see, the `key` is assumed to be a string. If you instead changed it like so, things would work as you expect:

```js
entries<T, U extends keyof T>(o: T): [U, T[U]][];
```

Now you obviously wouldn't want to update the typings on a standard library - so you could instead create your own typed function like so:

```js
const objectEntries = <T, U extends keyof T>(inputObject: T) => {
  return Object.entries(inputObject) as [U, T[U]][]
}
```

Using this you should get the typings you're looking for, and

```js
objectEntries(data.level_1.mapTiles).forEach(([
  tileType, // correctly inferred as "tree" | "rock"
  data
]) => {})
```

[image]